# SSH not working [ /bin/sh: Permission denied ]

Tags: ssh, android-permissions, permission-denied, user-permissions

```
test@2023:~$ ssh root@10.42.0.201

The authenticity of host '10.42.0.201 (10.42.0.201)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0TSeay4Ywqc69Inkfk0i/t5lJ8sXKSD/lLM2PuN5/d4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? 
yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/test/.ssh/known_hosts).
root@10.42.0.201's password: 
/bin/sh: Permission denied
Connection to 10.42.0.201 closed.
```

Why is getting permission denied error even after successful authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try by changing the **SELinux** mode to ***permissive***. It resolves your problem.

-- #DEFAULT_ENFORCING = "enforcing"

++ DEFAULT_ENFORCING = "permissive"